# Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (Trusty Tahr) -- SSH

Tags: 14.04, ssh, openssh

I am trying to start the ssh service on an install of Trusty Tahr.

> sudo service start ssh
>   start: unrecognized service
>
> sudo systemctl start ssh
>   sudo: systemctl: command not found

Is the syntax for this OS version different?

Looking for the package gives me

> which ssh
>   /usr/bin/ssh
>
> locate ssh
>   returns a lot of things with openssh-client

Comment: If you're setting up your machine now, you may want to go ahead and use 18.04, which is the latest LTS.  [14.04.5 End of Life is in 2019](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).  If you decide to use a more recent LTS, you'll run `systemctl restart sshd`.  `service` may still work, but `systemctl` is the new method.

Comment: It's not clear if you are trying to start an ssh *client* or *server*. Ubuntu desktop flavors lack an ssh server at install. Adding an ssh server is trivial in the Software Center or using Apt.

Comment: The old version of Ubuntu is intentional. I am attempting to set up a lab machine that I could not figure out an exploit to that is still bugging me.  Service comes back as "unrecognized service" and systemctl comes back as "command not found".

Answer (score 1):

ssh is the client application.  If you want to start the service to accept ssh connection, that is sshd.  Try

```
sudo service start sshd
```

If that doesn't work, make sure openssh-server is installed.  If not, install it and then try the above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am attempting to install openssh-server but it is hanging trying to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com. I have network access but this hangs. This is in a VM and I can successfully ssh to my host but not to the VM.

Comment: Do you have network access to the internet, or just in your lab?  If you do not have access to the internet, you may have to configure your proxy settings.  You can try setting the environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy to your proxy server and then try installing openssh-server.

Comment: While setting up the machine I have set the network adapter to Bridged Mode so that I can download software. When I get the machine all set up I will switch it back to NAT.

Comment: Can the host get to the internet?  If so, can the VM then get to the internet?  If the host can, but the VM cannot, then configure the proxy settings in your VM.  Then check if the VM can get to the internet.

Comment: Yes the host and the VM both have internet access.

Comment: Are there any messages in any logs or that appear on the screen when trying to install openssh-server?  Have you tried a mirror repository?  What is the output of "sudo apt-get update"?

Comment: UPDATE: I reinstalled the OS on this VM and sudo ssh start works just fine now. I can ssh to my host and to other VM's but I still get a "timeout" or "No route to host" when I try to SSH to this openssh-server.

Comment: Are you doing sudo ssh start, or sudo sshd start?  If you are doing sudo ssh start, you are telling the ssh client to try to connect to a server called start.  If you are doing sudo sshd start, I'm not sure what will happen since I do not think sshd knows how to handle an argument called start.  Remember, exact command you are running is critical to helping you troubleshoot your problem.  You can also run commands like "ps -ef | grep sshd" to see if the ssh server daemon is really running on your VM.

Comment: That is my fault. sudo start ssh works, and sudo status ssh shows me "start/running, pricess ####". I can also make a connection from this VM to my host or another VM.
What I am having trouble with now is making an ssh connection to this VM from my host or another VM.

Comment: You are running a command called status?  I do not have that command on my ubuntu 18.04 system.

Comment: The "sudo status ssh" command is being run from a VM with Ubuntu 14.04.5 running. I am trying to re-create a VM from an exploit lab that I could not figure out. I need this VM (14.04.5) to accept ssh connections, which it is not doing.

Comment: What is the exact command you are running to get the status of the ssh server daemon process?  I doubt it is "sudo status ssh"  If you really are running "sudo status ssh" could you edit your original question and copy and paste the command and its output?

Comment: I think some signals are getting crossed. My original question asked about the syntax for starting the ssh daemon in 14.04.5. I tried using "sudo service start ssh" and "sudo systemctl start ssh". Neither of these were working so I asked if 14.04.5 used a different syntax.
I have since been able to start the daemon with "sudo start ssh" and I can verify it is running with "sudo status ssh". Again this is Ubuntu 14.04.5
Now I need it to accept outside ssh connections, this is what I am currently stuck on.

Comment: Ok.  Let's try a different approach.  What is the output of "ps -ef | grep sshd"?

Comment: root     3280        1  0  11:49  ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
alfred  3956  2264  0  13:48  pts/0  00:00:00 grep  --color=auto  ssh

Comment: Ok.  So, the ssh daemon is running.  Good.  What is the IP address of this VM?  From the VM, can you ping your host server?  On your host server, can you ping your VM?  On the VM, can you ping some other lab server?  On that other lab server, can you ping your VM?

Comment: Okay. I feel dumb now. I just set up the Ubuntu VM on a bridged adapter and I can ssh into it. It was set up on NAT and I was unable to ping or ssh to it. I guess I am misunderstanding NAT. As far as this thread is concerned, the issue is resolved. If you could shed some light on my NAT issue that would be great, I could also do some reading.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to have been able to help.  In regards to NAT-ing, typically NAT is used to allow a client access to the rest of the world, but not necessarily allow the rest of the world access to it.  This is done by giving the client a private IP (e.g. 192.168.1.2).  The device doing the NAT-ing will take requests from the client and change the packet header to make it look like it is coming from it.  It keeps this state info so that when the outside entity responds to the client's packet, the device can rewrite the packet header and forward it onto the client.

Comment: If you want to let the outside access the client, you can set up port forwarding on the device doing the NAT-ing.  This lets the device know that any requests coming into port X should be forward to the client on port Y.  The client then has a service listening on port Y.  Hope this helps.